# Most efficient method of communication (Theory)

Tags: arduino, performance

I have an Arduino Uno connected to a PC via USB and I am communicating via serial to a temperature sensor from PHP.

At present, the temperature sensor records a value and sends it straight down the serial connection to the PC. However, this may not be read for a long period of time. Therefore, I think this method may be inefficient.

I was thinking I could listen on the Arduino for a serial message from the PX requesting the temperature before actually checking it and sending the message back to the PC via serial, therefore becoming more efficient as its not checking the temperature every 0.1 seconds.

My Questions are as follows:

1. Is this actually worth doing from a code efficiency point?
2. Is there a better way to improve this than my suggested method?
3. Would these changes improve battery performance (Eg if I was using a
   different communication model and not Serial and therefore might
   need a batteries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1:** Since you already have the routines to measure the temperature and then send it to the PC there should not be much coding left to do to wait for a trigger from the PC before performing the routine.

**A2:** There always is a 'better' way :)

**A3:** If your µC does not have many other tasks to perform that keep it busy you can definitely save a *lot* of juice by putting the µC to sleep between those short periods of activity - which you should do anyway when running off batteries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you think of a better way off hand to improve the efficiency?

Comment: That depends on what kind of 'efficiency' you mean. Efficient in code size/ROM/RAM/IO pin usage, efficient in power consumption, efficient in CPU load, ...?

Comment: Ok, I think I have more reading to do. I've implemented the serial request method, so I am happy for now. Thanks for your help